# Two Command buttons using MVVM but only first 1 fires

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have 2 command imagebuttons and 1 button using MVVM binding but only the imagebuttons will fire. I have them all in my model defined the exact same way like.
**XAML:**

```
<Imagebutton x:Name="imgSelection1" Source = "{Binding Questions}" Command="{Binding ImageSelectionCommand}".../>
<Imagebutton x:Name="imgSelection2" Source = "{Binding Questions}" Command="{Binding ImageSelectionCommand}".../>
<Button x:Name="betPoints" Text="0" Command="{Binding BetPointsCommand}".../>
```

**Model:**

```
public class Question
{
    public ICommand ImageSelectionCommand{ get; set; }
    public EventHandler PressedEventHandler;

    public ICommand BetPointsCommand { get; set; }
    public EventHandler ClickedEventHandler;
    

    public Question()
    {
        ImageSelectionCommand= new Command(() => OnQSelected()); // SET BREAKPOINT HERE NEVER STEPS TO BetPointsCommand line???
        BetPointsCommand = new Command(() => OnBetPoints());
    }

    public void OnQSelected()
    {
        PressedEventHandler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void OnBetPoints()
    {
        ClickedEventHandler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**Model View:**
ObservableCollection add like:

```
questions.Add(new Question { 
  ... PressedEventHandler = ImageSelected, ClickedEventHandler = BetPoints }
 );
```

Any thoughts since I've seen this in multiple examples that this is the "correct" way to define a command in MVVM albeit they only defined 1 command function.

Comment: Where do you set `PressedEventHandler` and `ClickedEventHandler`?

Comment: It is not clear enough the link between what you are expecting and the code you have. Are you using any mvvm framework ? if yes please mention it.

Comment: Along with other properties in the ObservableCollection add like: questions.Add(new Question { ...  PressedEventHandler = ImageSelected, ClickedEventHandler = BetPoints });
ImageSelected fires BetPoints does not.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the shared code in local site, and it works.

Only bind it as follows:

```
Question question = new Question();
BindingContext = question;
```

And add breakpoint inside **Question** class, and they are all invoked.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. There is no Source parameter on a button but there is ImageSource but that did not work. Also tried this  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference questionsPage}, Path=BindingContext.BetPointsCommand}" but that also did not work.

Comment: @Rick Sorry, that's a mistake. I have tested your code in local site, it works. If you have time, you could share a sample project link here.